# How can I approximate a character's jump in terrestrial circumstances in 2 dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I'd like to start with the 2-dimensional case to establish simple algorithms for an engine in a simulated environment to approximate physics of a human-sized character jumping long distances with gravity and air resistance, except to approximate air resistance so as to reduce the computational strain.

For a typical human, this air resistance doesn't come into play often because we're so massive in proportion to our small jumps, but, I'm trying to model this for a character that can jump large distances with a lot of strength.

Let's say a character jumps diagonally with some initial velocity, at any angle for that matter (both up from the ground or down from the ceiling after clinging to it). How do I model the fact that air gradually tries to stop the character no matter what direction they jump in? There is some degree of friction in proportion to the velocity itself.

I'm guessing there's a system of differential equations that model this, but I haven't studied physics in some years, so the specifics of what I need to do for this are lost on me.

Can we obtain an exact solution of the x-y velocities in terms of elementary functions (or at least known functions)? Or if not, can we approximate the differential system with a Taylor expansion or linearization? We may lose attributes like "terminal" velocity in that case, but as long as there is an approximation of friction in proportion to the velocity that gradually stops the character, that is sufficient.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but "aerodynamics" can, in some sense, be approximated by fluid mechanics, and since I didn't see an aerodynamics tag, I put "fluid-dynamics".

Comment: Why do you want to model Air resistance?

Comment: To fake a degree of realism, and to stop characters from going to fast too quickly with purely quadratic positional changes. I'm also considering implementing a "gliding" feature which of course doesn't work without air resistance. If you think air resistance is completely negligible for humanoids I can consider that, but the characters would be jumping, say, 10 meters at a time.

Comment: Okay, well is there a way you can demonstrate this? Like maybe some approximation of a solution to differential equations shows that, if a humanoid character is able to jump so that they land 10 meters away, the air resistance wouldn't really make that much of a difference, they'd be off by only a few inches at most?

Comment: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node29.html I think this js what your looking for

Comment: $V_{t} = \frac{mg}{c} $ should be different for each character, with c being larger for characters with a glider. This encorporates all physics, like terminal velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can choose to make the air resistance proportional to $v$ or $v^2$, which I believe to be more physically realistic.  I'll choose $v$ because it's mathematically simpler, then we have the following in two dimensions:

$${\ddot x} = -c {\dot x} \;\;\;\; {\ddot y} = -g - c {\dot y}$$

The second equation has the same form as the first, so let's only worry about integrating it.  Dividing by the LHS and integrating (and choosing the  expression $\frac{1}{c}\ln C$ for our integration constant for later simplicity), we have${}^{1}$:

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{{\ddot y} dt}{g + c{\dot y}} &= \int -1 dt\\
\frac{1}{c}\ln\left(g + c{\dot y}\right) &= \frac{1}{c}\ln C - t\\
g + c {\dot y} &= Ce^{-ct}\\
c{\dot y} &= Ce^{-ct} - g\\
cy &= cy_{0} - gt - \frac{C}{c}e^{-ct}\\
y &= y_{0} - \frac{g}{c}t - \frac{C}{c^{2}}e^{-ct}
\end{align}$$

We can fix the value of $C$ by saying, at time $t=0$, $v = v_{y0}$, and we have:

$cv_{y0} = C - g \rightarrow C = cv_{y0} +g$

And, noting that the x direction is the same derivation, but with $g=0$, we get the general solution:

$$y = y_{0} - \frac{g}{c}t - \frac{cv_{y0} +g}{c^{2}}e^{-ct}$$
$$x = x_{0}  - \frac{v_{x0}}{c}e^{-ct}$$

it's a bit of a tricky calculus game to show that your normal kinematics pop back out if you take the limit $c \rightarrow 0$, but it does work out [though I should point out that there is a bit of dishonesty in the names $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$ above if you do this].

Also, I'd second the objection above -- you probably could completely get away with computing a terminal velocity for each character using that value of $c$ and the speed above, and then just treating them as quadratic until they hit terminal velocity, and then they just stay at terminal velocity.

EDIT:

Ok, so, now let's do some analysis of the behavior:

$$\dot y = v_{y} = \frac{cv_{y0} + g}{c}e^{-ct} - \frac{g}{c}$$
$$\dot x = v_{x} = v_{x0}e^{-ct}$$

So, that constant $c$ defines a unit with which the x velocity decays to zero, and with which the $y$ velocity decays from an initial velocity of $v_{y0}$ to a late-time velocity $-\frac{g}{c}$, which is the terminal velocity of the motion.  So, for a high value of $c$, the motion both decays more quickly, and reaches a lower terminal velocity.  Now, going back to a vectorized version of Newton's Second law that I used to derive the initial equations, we have:

$$m{\vec a} = \sum{\vec F} = -m {\vec g} - mc {\vec v}$$

for mathematical simplicity (I wanted a simple equation to show how easy this equation is to solve), I cheated a bit in naming this $mc$ here.  Realistically, we'd call this $mc$ some variable $\alpha$, which would depend on the shape of the object, and how well it catches the air, and then we'd have the above equation written as:

$$m{\vec a} = \sum{\vec F} = -m {\vec g} - \alpha {\vec v}$$

which then would give what I called $c$ as "really" being $\alpha/m$.  So, the larger the mass of an object, the smaller the value of $c$, and the less air resistance matters for that object.

${}^{1}$choosing $c$ to be some constant that depends on the mass of the object, how much area it takes up passing through the air, how sticky it is to the air, and the density of the air

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So I'm dealing with a vector, in 2 dimensions, and I'm given a linear-looking ODE. Is there a way I can approximate the solution with a matrix exponential?

Comment: it's a system of ODEs, in two dimensions.

Comment: Okay, but to be clear and very sure before I recommend that to other people, is that a yes or no on the matrix-exponential? Is this as simple as it looks?

Comment: Can these simple equations also explain why drag-forces tend to overrun very low-mass objects?

Comment: @StackQuest: you could certainly just converthe above into a matrix equation if you wanted, is that your question?  

And yes, you can use this to explain that.  I'll amend the answer